# Asp.Net MVC 4 with Blend for Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, blend

I haven't seen so far, but can you use Blend to create (shared) layouts in asp.net mvc 4?

Comment: do you want to use nested layouts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the only HTML you can do in Blend is for building Windows Store apps. Though HTML is HTML in whatever context you use it and it should be theoretically possible to design an HTML site in Blend, it's not build for that. ASP.Net can't be used.

I admit Blend would be an awesome tool for designing regular web applications. and I personally hope there will be support for that in the future.